# Bootstrap image not responsive

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I tried multiple solutions but I cannot get my image (png) to be responsive...

My html :

```
<img src="images/hobby_cars.png" alt="" class="img-responsive hobbies" />
```

My CSS :

```
.hobbies  {
    padding-top: 3%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I'm seeing what's wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/fejcrr9e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set a width on my CSS and it works !

```
.hobbies  {
    padding-top: 3%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add max-width to the img

```
img.hobbies {
 max-width:100%
}
```